# Socket.IO connection issue when plotting d3.js chart with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sockets, d3.js, websocket, socket.io

I am working on a project which main goal is to send and plot floats from an Arduino board to a d3.js chart with JavaScript. I am using **Socket.IO** for the client-server connection and everything works fine with the firsts values recieved until a random moment when it stops plotting and the following errors are received on the browser console:

```html
> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=9pXgEjLWag4PB_3-AAtJ' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

> index.js:83 POST http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MwowjHu&sid=9pXgEjLWag4PB_3-AAtJ 400 (Bad Request)
```

I guess the problem is due to something wrong with the Socket.IO connection but I have no clue how to fix it. Any help please?

The Socket.IO code for the Server is:

```js
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = socket(server);

sender.on('message', function(EEG) {
    io.once('connection', function(socket) { //io.on is not working properly...
        let newv = (Math.random());

        socket.emit('messages', messages);
           });
});
sender.bind(UDPport, '192.168.0.102');

server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log("Server running on http://localhost:8080");
});
```

and the Client side is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  receivedata();//receive called in button.onclick (check full code)
  function recievedata() {
        var socket = 0;

        setInterval(function() {
            socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
            socket.on('messages', function(EEG) {

                document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = (socket.id);
         
                updateChart(EEG); 
      
            })
        }, 100);


    };
```

**Server.js Full Code:**

```js
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = socket(server);**

app.use(express.static('public')); // index.html y el cliente.js folder 


//-----------DATA-RECEIVER---------------------------------------------

var dgram = require("dgram");
var sender = dgram.createSocket('udp4'); //Sender = Arduino ESP32 Board
var UDPport = 10101;

var buf = new ArrayBuffer(4);
const ui8 = new Uint8Array(buf);
const f32 = new Float32Array(buf);


sender.on('listening', function() {
    console.log('UDP server listening on ' + sender.address().address);
});


sender.on('message', function(EEG) {

    //---------BYTE-TO-FLOAT----------------------------------------------

      EEG.forEach(function(b, i) {
        ui8[i] = b;

    });
    //---------SEND-DATA-TO-CLIENT-**SOCKET**---------------------------------------

    var messages = f32[0];

    console.log(messages);
    **io.once('connection', function(socket) {
            socket.emit('messages', messages);**
     
    });
});
sender.bind(UDPport, '192.168.0.102');

server.listen(8080, function() {
    console.log("Server running on http://localhost:8080");
});
```

**Client.js Full code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var button = document.getElementById("startbutton");
    var button2 = document.getElementById("stopbutton");
    new Boolean(stop);

    button.onclick = function() {
        console.log(this.id + " START!");
        stop = false;
        receivedata();
       
    };

    button2.onclick = function() {
        console.log(this.id + " STOP!");
        stop = true;
    };

    function receivedata() {
        var socket = 0;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**SOCKETS**-----------------------
        setInterval(function() {
            **socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
            socket.on('messages', function(EEG) {**

                document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = (socket.id);
                if (stop) {
                     updateChart(0);
                } else {
                updateChart(EEG);
                   }
            **})**
        }, 100);
    };

     //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------DIMENSIONS--------------------
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    // Create the Scalable Vector Graphics container and set the origin.
    var svg = d3.select("#chart"),
        margin = { top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 50 },
        width = Math.floor(svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right),
        height = Math.floor(svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom);

    var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------DATA----------------------

    let data = [{ values: [] }]; //Dadas input que se muestra del graph

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ATRIBUTOS-------------------

    g.append("defs").append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip2")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------DOMAINS-----------------------
    // set the ranges and Y domain
    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
        y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
        z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    y.domain([-1.5, 1.5]);

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------LINE-------------------------
    //Define the line
    var line = d3.line()
        .curve(d3.curveBasis) //definimos tipo de curva
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.time); }) //para el eje x definimos el tiempo
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.eeg); }); //para el eje y definimos los datos EEG

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------AXIS-------------------------
    //Definimos el eje x
    var x_axis = d3.axisBottom()
        .scale(x);

    var x_axis_svg = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

    // Add the Y Axis
    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .attr("fill", "#000")

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------NI-ZORRA-------------------------

    let pathsG = g.append("g").attr("id", "paths").attr("class", "paths")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip2)");



    // parse the date / time
    //var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%H:%M:%S.%L");


    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------UPDATE-DATA----------------------
    let duration = 200; //how quickly to move (will look jerky if less that data input rate)
    let limit = 100; // how many datapoints, total points = (duration * limit)

    function updateChart(EEG) {

        let now = new Date(); //Calcula fecha actual
        console.log(now);

        data.forEach((e) => {
            let last = e.values.length ? e.values[e.values.length - 1].speed : 10;
            let newv = Math.round(Math.min(100, Math.max(2, last + (Math.random() * 6) - 3)));
            //   EEG = 0;
            e.values.push({
                time: now,
                eeg: EEG,
            });


            console.log(data[0].values.length, "=", EEG, '\n', '-------------------------------------------');

        });


        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------SLIDE-AXIS-----------------
        // Cambio de dominio para el eje x
        x.domain([now - ((limit - 2) * duration), now - duration])

        // Transición del eje x por la izquierda
        x_axis_svg.transition().duration(duration).ease(d3.easeLinear, 2).call(x_axis);

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------UPDATE-AXIS---------------------
        //Join
        var minerG = pathsG.selectAll(".minerLine").data(data);
        var minerGEnter = minerG.enter()
            //Enter
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "minerLine")
            .merge(minerG);

        //Join
        var minerSVG = minerGEnter.selectAll("path").data(function(d) {
            return [d];
        });

        var minerSVGenter = minerSVG.enter()
            //Enter
            .append("path").attr("class", "line")
            .style("stroke", function(d) {
                return z(d.id);
            })
            .merge(minerSVG)
            //Update
            .transition()
            .duration(duration)
            .ease(d3.easeLinear, 10)
            .attr("d", function(d) {
                return line(d.values)
            })
            .attr("transform", null)


    }


});
```